# How to boot again with Windows 95 after a byte-by-byte HDD copy?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, data-recovery, ddrescue

**Background**

I have a very old PATA HDD (1998 Fujitsu 3.2GB) plugged into a very old computer (Pentium 2 / Asus P2L97 motherboard) with one bootable partition (Windows 95 and Fat32 file system). As expected this HDD dies with a lot of [S.M.A.R.T](https://hddlife.com/eng/smart.html) alerts.

My goal is not to recover the data but to get the copy of old HDD to the new HDD (2003 PATA WD 80GB) to boot again.

I saved the entire old HDD with `ddrescue` (booting from [systemrescue)](https://www.system-rescue.org/) to an image file (rescue.img on USB drive) after plugged the failing HDD on a newer computer, like explain in the [ddrescue manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html). Unfortunately when I try to restore the image on a newer HDD the MBR is corrupted and I can not boot.

**What I did in detail:**

```
[root@sysrescue]#  ddrescue /dev/sda /mnt/usb/SAVEDD/rescue.img /mnt/usb/SAVEDD/rescue.mapfile
GNU ddrescue 1.26
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
ipos:             305664 B,  non-trimmed:  0 B,       current rate:       0 B/s
opos:             305664 B,  non-scraped:  1024 B,    average rate:    184 kB/s
non-tried:        0 B,       bad-sector:   154624 B,  error rate:    1024 B/s
rescued:          3243 MB,   bad areas:    2,         run time:  4h 53m 15s
pct rescued:      99.99%,    read errors:  305,       remaining time:         n/a
Finished
```

Complete [rescue log](https://sebsauvage.net/paste/?2a686a0301e7a168#AUo1sybaGEiVNTugtGe/z2YTJNU9smKzyfoUbs3KLwE=) (7Mo) and [rescue map file](https://sebsauvage.net/paste/?d04d31e8592ac08d#aqdi4nNIGpctFRHq7xAez6bASTwbnurRT3g1D5yRm0c=)

The image file looks fine with `fdisk`

```
[root@sysrescue]# fdisk -l copy_rescue.img

Disk copy_rescue.img: 3.02 GB, 3243663360 bytes, 6335280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5902d932

Device             Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size  Id  Type
copy_rescue.img1   *         63  6330239  6330177    3G   b  W95 FAT32
```

but `file` shows corrupted MBR and partition table.

```
[root@sysrescue]# file -s copy_rescue.img
copy_rescue.img: DOS/MBR boot sector MS-MBR 9M english at offset 0x10+0xFF "Invalid partition table" at offset 0x127 "Error loading operating system" at offset 0x146 "Missing operating system", disk signature 0x5902d932, created with driveID 0x80; partition 1 : ID=0xb, active, start-CHS (0x0, 1, 1), end-CHS (0x310, 127, 63), startsector 63, 6330177 sectors
```

I tried copying the image to a "newer", bigger and healty SATA HDD (2003 WD 80GB) after cleaning

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
dd: writing to '/dev/sda': no space left on device
80026361856 bytes (80 GB, 75GiB) copied
ddrescue -f /mnt/usb/SAVEDD/rescue.img /dev/sda restore.mapfile
```

Complete [restore map file](https://sebsauvage.net/paste/?e80e30f6c3592358#Fc9oSqOUnD3cyHOKkC1sYp3JPwq1KuSle233cGOno0s=)

The resulting partitioning is strange, seems good on /dev/sda

```
[root@sysrescue]# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 74.53 GB, 80026361856 bytes, 156301488 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD800BB-00CA
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5902d932

Device      Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size  Id  Type
/dev/sda1   *         63  6330239  6330177    3G   b  W95 FAT32
```

but totally wrong on `/dev/sda1` and HDD is not even recognized by the BIOS of the old computer.

My question is why am I getting a corrupted partition table when restoring?How can I boot with the newer HDD? What should I expect to see when I copy a very old booting Win95 3GB HDD (with dd or ddrescue) to a "newer" 80GB HDD?

I tried to rebuild the partition table with `testdisk` without success, but I'm not sure this is the right approach. Futhermore `testdisk` alert about a mistake in HDD heads/cylinder geometry.

Should I dig the direction of testdisk and MBR/Partition Table repair or is it a copy/ddrescue issue ?

**EDIT 1:

Old BIOS detect new HDD**
I solved the old BIOS not detecting the new HDD by reducing the capacity of the new HDD (with drive overlay) and copying the image of old HDD to the new HDD again

```
ddrescue -f /mnt/usb/SAVEDD/rescue.img /dev/sda restore.mapfile
fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 33.8 GB, 33820284928 bytes
128 heads, 63 sectors/track, 8191 cylinders, total 66055244 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5902d932

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63     6330239     3165088+   b  W95 FAT32
```

but some pbm persist:

- [the OS do not boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkTTY.png) even after a table partition fixing with `Testdisk`
- `Testdisk` detect some CHS mismatch `Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 128 (FAT) != 255 (HD)`

[Here](https://sebsauvage.net/paste/?91069f51b9424d3a#c1AR60rKUsGJqUg5Ena1kXBoIHm97CWeg7HUPg8bM6M=) is the complete testdisk.log

How to boot the OS after a `ddrescue` copy?

**EDIT 2: Old BIOS find Windows 95**

I rebuilt the MBR of the new HDD as follow

- boot with DOS floppy disk
- `A: fdisk /mbr`

Now I have a [windows 95 booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHZT7.png) but crash without error message (shutdown of the computer).

I tried to launch ['step-by-step confirmation'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eILzQ.png) and the booting process fails at

```
WIN [Enter=Y, Esc=N]?Y
Load all Windows drivers [Enter=Y, Esc=N]?Y
C:\WINDOWS\system\vmm32.vxd: Missing/unable to load.
Press any key to continue...
```

VMM32 seems to be a critical system file but I can still boot the system in Command Prompt Mode and probably repair it, because this file is at the [good place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA8vY.png).

```
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM>dir vmm32.vxd /s
    Volume in drive C has no label 
    Volume Serial Number is 232E-1BD3
Directory of C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM
VMM32  VXD   709.556   16.07.98   20:39  
       1 file(s)     709.556 bytes
Total files listed: 
    1 file(s) 709.556 bytes
    0 dir(s) 2.849.947.648 bytes free
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM>
```

Comment: `fdisk -l /dev/sda1` is meaningless because there is no partition table in a partition. We don't nest partitions. The garbage you see on `sda1` is not-a-partition-table interpreted as a partition table. The BIOS of the old computer does not recognize the bigger disk *maybe* because of this: [BIOS hard drive limits](https://dfarq.homeip.net/bios-hard-drive-limits/).

Comment: Could you show your testdisk log file?

Comment: @r2d3 I added the testdisk.log file

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski Thank you, I fix it by reducing the capacity of the disk with a drive overlay but I can not boot the OS. I edited my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of hassle I solved my problem as follows :

1. Update motherboard BIOS
2. Reduce the capacity of the new HDD with [drive overlay](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24593/24778) to match the size of both hard disks (due to a specific bug in the latest 'final official' BIOS version of my motherboard [like explain by user3840170](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24647/24778))
   [image: Drive Overlay]
3. Make a copy of the old HDD image to the new HDD with `ddrescue` (see above)
4. Repair the MBR with `fdisk /mbr` (booting from a DOS [windows 95](https://winworldpc.com/product/microsoft-windows-boot-disk/95-osr2x) floppy)
5. Boot the system in command prompt mode (press F8 after [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test))
6. Repair file system with `scandisk` (CHKDSK can not)[image: CHKDSK]

What did NOT work :

- Fixed MBR (Master Boot Record) with specific tools like [Ranish Partition Manager](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24246/how-to-determine-bios-provided-int-13h-hard-disk-geometry-and-how-to-fix-the)
- Fixed CHS (cylinder, head and sector) values in BIOS
- Fixed HDD mode detection in BIOS (LBA/large/CHS)
- Reinstall the system file with `sys c:` like propose by [TestDisk manual](https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk.pdf) (p 35)
- Trusting the robustness of floppy disks in 2022

Thanks to all of you and the folks at retrocomputing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why am I getting a corrupted partition table when restoring?

Fdisk tells you that your partition has type "b".

If you look this up in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type

the description field denotes "FAT32 with CHS addressing"

This partitions needs to be addressed by using a triple consisting of cylinder, head and sector.
When your disk was mounted in your P2L97 machine your BIOS contained a parameter set of maximum C,H and S value for the whole disk.

If that parameter set changes, any request for an individual sector based on c,h,s addressing will point to a different sector.

As you want the new disk to run in your old machine, I guess you need to duplicate your disk on the old machine using the same CHS setting for both disks. Furthermore the CHS setting should be equal to the one that was set when removing your slowly dying disk.

The problem is that a modern live linux might not run on your old machine and an old linux version will not contain ddrescue. But you could use dd instead by restricting it to the areas that could be recovered. That way you do not stress the disk and won't get trapped in that dammaged area as exhibited in the ddrescue map file.

Comment: @ r2d3  Thank you, so if I understand your explanation: the CHS parameters are neither stored on the disk nor in the disk firmware but only in the BIOS of the motherboard? I know the CHS setting of old HDD (786/128/63), what do you think of the following: 1) Reduce capacity of new HDD to 3,245,211,648 bytes (C x H x S x 512) with a drive overlay 2) Plug the new HDD in the new PC with modern live linux while forcing CHS 786/128/63 in BIOS (+ addressing mode) and make copy 3) Plug the new HDD in the old PC with same forcing in CHS BIOS setting (786/128/63)?

Comment: That sounds useful. I would backup your faulty copy on your new drive because you don't know how many sectors your old drive will disclose. Compare the log files to know. A backup of your copy could be helpful once you found out how the mapping is like.