# How to boot a Windows 98 disk image restored in a larger disk?

Tags: bios, mbr, ms-dos, fat32, windows-98

Let me explain what I did in detail:

1. found that the Samsung 1.6GB IDE HDD in a Windows 98 PC (Pentium 200MHz) was failing
2. detached it and dumped it using `gddrescue` through a slightly newer PC running; it reported a few (<10) sectors unreadable
3. restored the disk dump into a 16BG SD card and attached it using an [SD-to-IDE adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08SK28S2Y)
4. performed IDE HDD auto-detection in BIOS, which found the adapter having a size of 8455 (with C/H/S = 16383/16/63)
5. attempted to boot getting "Invalid system disk - Replace the disk, and then press any key"

At this point I did many other attempts but my current conclusion is that the C/H/S selected in BIOS for the new disk do not match the original disk, thus boot cannot happen. NOTE: the unreadable clusters are not affecting the boot since I can boot this disk dump fine with VirtualBox

This is the BPB information of the FAT32 type "b" I am trying to boot:

```
JMP opcodes: EB 58 90
OEM Name: MSWIN4.1
Bytes per sector: 512
Sectors per cluster: 2
# reserved sectors: 32
# FATs on volume: 2
# root directory entries: 0
Sectors in volume: 0
Media descriptor type: 248
Sectors per FAT: 0
Sectors per Track: 63
# heads: 64
# hidden sectors: 63
Huge sectors in volume: 1636929
FAT Type: 32
Drive number: 128
Signature: 29
Volume ID: 1078731261
Volume Label: WIN98      
FAT Type: FAT32   
Root Cluster: 5848
```

The only disk dump that I can now boot is an old Windows 3.1 disk image, which has this BPB information:

```
JMP opcodes: EB 3C 90
OEM Name: MSDOS5.0
Bytes per sector: 512
Sectors per cluster: 64
# reserved sectors: 1
# FATs on volume: 2
# root directory entries: 512
Sectors in volume: 0
Media descriptor type: 248
Sectors per FAT: 250
Sectors per Track: 63
# heads: 64
# hidden sectors: 63
Huge sectors in volume: 4088385
FAT Type: 16
Drive number: 128
Signature: 29
Volume ID: 955817494
Volume Label: MS-DOS_6   
FAT Type: FAT16
```

Things I tried, without succeeding:

1. manually setting C/H/S of the new disk to same as old disk (780/3120/63), gives Primary master failure on POST and ignoring it doesn't help
2. rebuilding the MBR with TestDisk
3. writing the TestDisk special MBR (does not boot, just hangs)
4. installing MS-DOS 7.1 with VirtualBox, then dumping the disk image
5. replacing the the MS-DOS on the Windows 3.1 working dump with MS-DOS 7
6. using Ventoy to boot ISOs, it does not support Windows 98 nor MS-DOS 7 which is needed for Windows 98
7. using Plop boot manager

How can I fix this boot problem? I cannot easily attach a CD-ROM nor floppy but I have a couple of these SD-to-IDE adapters and other IDE drives. Thanks for any ideas!

Other questions I found related/interesting: [How to boot again with Windows 95 after a byte-by-byte HDD copy?](https://superuser.com/questions/1724339/how-to-boot-again-with-windows-95-after-a-byte-by-byte-hdd-copy)

Comment: This question is perhaps better suited for https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should I post it there and delete this one? Or wait for a moderator's advice?

Comment: Maybe CF card is better option since it's actually an ATA drive internally.

Comment: That wouldn't change anything since the geometry would still be different; also: I don't think it should be discussed in comments to the question

Comment: 780/3120/63 - seems very odd for chs as 254 is max for heads. Have you tried set partition type to 0x0C to perhaps force it using LBA addressing? Just a hunch, so long since I messed with 98.

Comment: Using a DOS/FREEDOS bootable USB, boot from it and type SYS C: - you may need to find the SYS.EXE program within the win98 system if it isn't included on the USB. Also make sure the main partition where the windows files are is set to ACTIVE

This will guarantee the system will boot.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas that can't work because I cannot boot from floppy/CD and you cannot SYS C: after booting from C:; also, I don't think we should discuss this in the comments to the question but in an answer.

Comment: please re-read my comment - get the freedos image installed to USB, then boot from that, not to actually use a floppy - this should work and if it does, i will add it as an answer